# Find the least ordinal $β>0$ such that $αβ=β$ (given arbitrary $α>1$)

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

The hint for this question was that $s=1+α+α^2+\cdots$ might be a candidate. While it's easy to check $αs=s$, it's not obvious how to check such $s$ is the least of all $β$ for which $αβ=β$.

Any hint would be appreciated :)

**Update**

Problem solved. Thanks go to Andrés E. Caicedo.

Comment: Suppose $t <s $. Then $t <s_n$, the $n $th partial sum.  For the least such $n $, estimate the size of $\alpha t $.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo: thank you for the help! I hope following this idea, what features is that the partial sum $s_n$ bounding $t$ would also bound $\alpha^k$ for all $k<\omega$, i.e. $s_n\geq\alpha^{\omega}$, which is impossible.

Comment: @Pteros: the FAQ encourages you to answer your own question if something solves it for you after you post it.  It would be good to post an answer, partly so we have an answer and partly so you have to write it up in more detail.  The second may help your understanding.  You will be able to accept your answer after some delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for Andrés E. Caicedo's hint and Ross Millikan's suggestion:

Let $s=1+\alpha+\alpha^{2}+\cdots$. Then $s=1+\alpha s$. Given $\alpha>1$, $\alpha s=\alpha+\alpha^{2}+\cdots$ is no less than $\omega$ and thus $1+\alpha s=\alpha s$.

It remains to show $s$ is the least ordinal which satisfies the equation $\alpha\beta=\beta$. We check that any $0<t<s$ is not a solution. Consider the partial sums of $s$: $s_{0} =1$, $s_{1} =1+\alpha$, ....
 Then $t<s$ implies there exists $n<\omega$ for which $t<s_{n}$. Suppose $t=\alpha t$, implying $t=\alpha^{k}t$ for all $k<\omega$. Thus $s_{n}>\alpha^{k}t\geq\alpha^{k}$ for all $k<\omega$, namely,

$s_{n}=1+\cdots+\alpha^{n}\geq\sup\left\{ \alpha^{k}|k<\omega\right\} =\alpha^{\omega}=\alpha^{(1+\cdots+n+1)+\omega}=\alpha^{1}\cdots\alpha^{n+1}\alpha^{\omega}$.

This is impossible, for we can prove by induction that $1+\cdots+\alpha^{n}<\alpha^{1}\cdots\alpha^{n+1}$. Assuming for all $k<n$, $1+\cdots+\alpha^{k-1}<\alpha^{1}\cdots\alpha^{k}$, we have

$1+\cdots+\alpha^{n-1}+\alpha^{n}<1+\cdots+\alpha^{n-1}+\alpha^{n+1}\leq\alpha^{1}\cdots\alpha^{n}+\alpha^{n+1}$.

Let $1+\delta=\alpha^{n+1}$, then

$\alpha^{1}\cdots\alpha^{n+1}=\alpha^{1}\cdots\alpha^{n}(1+\delta)=\alpha^{1}\cdots\alpha^{n}+\alpha^{1}\cdots\alpha^{n}\delta>\alpha^{1}\cdots\alpha^{n}+\alpha^{1+\cdots+n}\geq\alpha^{1}\cdots\alpha^{n}+\alpha^{n+1}$

as expected.